# Get full access token from Auth0 using angular-oauth2-oidc library

Tags: angular, auth0, angular-oauth2-oidc

I have [the `angular-oauth2-oidc`](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc) library set up to use with Auth0. However, Auth0 keeps sending me a really short access token, e.g. `mSNhEfdDHK6t-kT5QweRtgec-FPGAsdfEw9`, instead of a full JWT token. Here's how to reproduce the issue:

1. Create a sample "API" in Auth0 that you want access to as a resource.
2. Create a SPA application set up for implicit flow in Auth0.
3. Follow the quick start from [`angular-oauth2-oidc`](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc) or clone [my sample repo](https://github.com/jeroenheijmans/sample-angular-oauth2-oidc-with-auth-guards).
4. Configure it along these lines:

   ```typescript
   export const authConfig: AuthConfig = {
     issuer: 'https://your-tenant-name.eu.auth0.com/',
     clientId: 'your-spa-client-id-here',
     redirectUri: window.location.origin + '/index.html',
     scope: 'openid profile email',
   };
   ```
5. Trigger the `initImplicitFlow()` call by clicking the login button on your application.

When you do so:

- Result: full JWT IdToken, but short AccessToken.
- Expected: both tokens full JWT tokens.

There is [this thread on the Auth0 community forums](https://community.auth0.com/t/how-to-get-an-access-token-in-jwt-format/6185) that explains why you get such an "opaque string" for an access token. The top, accepted answer mentions things that I'm already doing (`sope` as I did, calling `/authorize`, etc). However, lower in that thread it mentions **setting the `audience` when calling `/authorize` is the solution**, which seems like a good thing anyways.

But how do you send along the `audience`? There is no such property on [the `AuthConfig` type](https://manfredsteyer.github.io/angular-oauth2-oidc/docs/classes/AuthConfig.html) to set it, and looking at the `initImplicitFlow()` source it just straight up changes `location.href` so there's no interception there either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You were almost there. Although it might be nice to have `audience` as a specific property on the `AuthConfig` type, there is already a way to configure it: use [the `customQueryParams`](https://manfredsteyer.github.io/angular-oauth2-oidc/docs/classes/AuthConfig.html#customQueryParams) for this:

```
export const authConfig: AuthConfig = {
  issuer: 'https://your-tenant-name.eu.auth0.com/',
  clientId: 'your-spa-client-id-here',
  redirectUri: window.location.origin + '/index.html',
  scope: 'openid profile email',
  customQueryParams: {
    audience: 'https://your-api-audience-id.example.com',
  },
};
```

The `audience` is the identifier you've configured in Auth0. Here's a screenshot from the management interface:

[image: Identifier is the Audience parameter]

Comment: This answer is gold! saved my day! :)